# How to solve Image slider moving too fast problem in Android?

Tags: java, android

In my Android project, I have created an Image slider. The Image slider contains two image and the duration of the sliding is 5000 ms and image stay period 5000ms.

Here is the method I have introduced to set the image sliding-

```
     private void init() {
        final float density = 
        mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        mPager.setAdapter(new SlidingImage_Adapter(mContext,coverImageList));

        indicator.setRadius(5 * density);
        NUM_PAGES =coverImageList.size();

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES) {
                    currentPage = 0;
                }
                mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
            }
        };
        Timer swipeTimer = new Timer();
        swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(Update);
            }
        }, 5000, 5000);

        indicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new 
        ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                currentPage = position;

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int pos, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int pos) {
            }
        });

    }
```

And here is the adapter class I have used to set the adapter for Image slider -

**SlidingImage_Adapter.java**

```
public class SlidingImage_Adapter extends PagerAdapter {


    private List<ModelBanner> imageModelArrayList;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;


    public SlidingImage_Adapter(Context context, List<ModelBanner> imageModelArrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.imageModelArrayList = imageModelArrayList;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageModelArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {
        View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slidingimages_layout, view, false);

        assert imageLayout != null;
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.image);


        Picasso.with(context).load(imageModelArrayList.get(position).getImagePath()).into(imageView);

        view.addView(imageLayout, 0);

        return imageLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now, the thing is, I have a swipe refresh in my Activity. So, when I swipe the screen to refresh, the image slider behaves in a different way. The images move very fast not following the set delay and period time.

I don't know why this problem occurs and how to solve this. So, it would nice if someone find the problem and suggest the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override default `viewPagerScroller` by custom scroller.

Recently a library of mine has been published on GitHub, named: [Jummania-Slider](https://github.com/Jumman04/Jummania-Slider)

In the library I used a custom scrolling class to control the moving speed of the `ViewPager`, which extends `Scroller`.

**in ViewPager:**

```
        viewPager.apply {
            try {
                val viewPagerScroller = ViewPager::class.java.getDeclaredField("mScroller")
                viewPagerScroller.isAccessible = true
                viewPagerScroller[this] = MyScroller(context)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
```

**MyScroller class**:

```
private inner class MyScroller(context: Context?) : Scroller(context) {

    /**
     * Created by Jummania on 08,November,2023.
     * Email: sharifuddinjumman@gmail.com
     * Dhaka, Bangladesh.
     */

    override fun startScroll(startX: Int, startY: Int, dx: Int, dy: Int, duration: Int) {
        super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, slidingDuration.toInt())
    }
}
```

You can use my [library](https://github.com/Jumman04/Jummania-Slider) if you want, or you can read the [source code](https://github.com/Jumman04/Jummania-Slider) of the [library](https://github.com/Jumman04/Jummania-Slider).

Answer (score -1):

Introduced to set the image sliding:

```
 private void init() {
    final float density = 
    mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    mPager.setAdapter(new SlidingImage_Adapter(mContext,coverImageList));

    indicator.setRadius(5 * density);
    NUM_PAGES =coverImageList.size();

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES) {
                currentPage = 0;
            }
            mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
        }
    };
    Timer swipeTimer = new Timer();
    swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(Update);
        }
    }, 5000, 5000);

    indicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new 
    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            currentPage = position;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int pos, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int pos) {
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what changes you made in the code you provided in the answer?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.